# How to solve system of differential equations with parametric form?

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations, calculus-of-variations

I was solving a calculus of variational problem in two variables.
After applying the conditions I get the following system of differential equations,
$$18xy'(t)+2yy'(t)=0\\4yx'(t)+18xx'(t)=0$$
I am not familiar with these kind of system. I searched online, but I couldn't find any. Anyone can help?

Edit: Minimize the $$I(x, y)=\int_{t_0}^t9x^2y'(t)-2y^2x'(t)$$

Comment: Unless I'm misunderstanding the problem, it almost looks like you have either $y'(t)=0$ or $18x+2y=0$ in the first line and similar in the second, giving specific values for $x,y$ in one case or each of $x,y$ being constant functions in $t$ in another.  Would you mind posting the original problem as well?

Comment: (In the case of specific values for $x,y$ it would appear that these would evaluate to $0$ each, suggesting that either my interpretation or some step prior to these lines has some error...)

Comment: $x$ and $y$ are functions of $t$

Comment: I get that...  I think the original problem will help clarify my confusion.

Comment: First equation is missing the factor 2 from the square derivative. Then you also get the factor $(9x+2y)$ as common factor in both equations.